# Recover InnoDB tables with FRM, ibdata1 and log files, but without ibd files (innodb_file_per_table = OFF)

Tags: innodb, recovery

I have spent three days investigating how to recover my database.    I have the ibdata1, the FRM, and the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files (It seems I don't have the ibd files since my configuration is as default: innodb_file_per_table = OFF)

The problem is that most of the recommendations on internet speak about the case when you have the ibd files, but, for my case (with the files I have), the possible solutions are downloading SW that is not available.

Please, I really need help to match the data so I can access the info.  I'll appreciate your help.

When I start the mysqld, there is no error messages at mysqld.log.

When it appears is when I try to access one of the InnoDB tables:

> 191008 15:17:13 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table DecopBD/acciones
>   from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for
>   the table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
>   files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files of
>   InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database? or,
>   the table contains indexes that this version of the engine doesn't
>   support. See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html how
>   you can resolve the problem.

Note that the DB has MyISAM and InnoDB tables.   The problem is just in the InnoDB.

Thankyou!!
Enrique

Comment: Did you try to start mysql ???

Comment: Yes, many times.. I've tryed starting with innodb_force_recovery 0 to 3..

Comment: You need to post the messages that the error log has. Rename the error log and then start mysqld and post the error message in the original question please.